# mathcal error with multicolumn multirow

Tags: tables, matrices, multirow, multicolumn, mathcal

I get the error `\mathcal allowed only in math mode` when I try to compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c c c c}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\mathcal{J}}} & a & b\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & a & b\\
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine when `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\mathcal{J}}}` is replaced with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathcal{J}}` (remove the multirow portion) or `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{J}}` (remove the mathcal).

Comment: `multirow` is typesetting the contents of the cell in LR mode, so you need, I think, to reenter maths mode explicitly within the cell.

Comment: Apparently `\multirow{2}{*}` drops out of `math` mode. Use `$\mathcal{J}$` inside

Comment: @cfr: You were quicker, you should write the answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Really, you didn't need to delete your answer. When I saw you were answering, I was going to just answer with the explanation and leave you to provide the workaround.

Comment: @cfr: The explanation is useful enough, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `multirow`'s documentation, when you specify the width of the multi-row cell explicitly, it sets the contents in a `\parbox` of the requested width. This would obviously switch to text mode so you'd need to re-enter maths mode explicitly within the cell.

When you specify the width as `*`, the contents is set in LR mode. So, again, you drop out of maths mode into text mode and need to re-enter maths mode explicitly within the cell.

The documentation does also point out that it is not designed to work with `array` environments, but only `tabular`. It does, however, include a number of tips and workarounds for using it in `array` environments so, if you are doing this, I'd suggest having a read to pick up some hints.

For example, the following compiles without error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c c c c}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\mathcal{J}$}} & a & b\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & a & b\\
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: re-entering maths mode]

Answer (score 1):

Using `\multirow` is similar to using `\multicolumn` and, when `p` is specified in the latter, math mode must be resumed in the argument also in `array`.

However, the arrangement you're looking for can be obtained without `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\;\mathcal{J}
&
\begin{matrix}
 a & b\\
 a & b\\
\end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]